# Is the stalk of an irreducible scheme at the generic point always a field?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, localization, affine-schemes

Let $X$ be an irreducible scheme. It can be proved that it has a unique generic point, i.e. there is a unique point $\xi \in X$ such that $\overline{\{ \xi \}} = X$. One can identify $\xi$ as the prime ideal $\sqrt{0} \in Spec(R) = U \subset X$, which is a prime ideal as $U$ is an open subset of $X$ and $X$ is irreducible, hence $U$ is irreducible. Now consider the stalk of $X$ at the point $\xi$. We have that:
$$ \mathcal{O}_{X, \xi} = R_{\sqrt{0}}. $$
Now, if $R$ is an integral domain, then $R_\sqrt{0} = R_{(0)} = Frac(R)$, where $Frac(R)$ is the fraction field of $R$, so $\mathcal{O}_{X,\xi}$ is a field. What about the general case? Is it always a field?

Comment: No, try $k[x]/(x^2)$.

Comment: It is irreducible: it's one point. The unique prime ideal is $(x)$.

Comment: @KReiser my bad yes, indeed. Also it is the same as $V(x^2)$ and its radical is $(x)$. So you suggest that it is a field if and only if $\sqrt(0) = 0$, i.e. there are no non-trivial nilpotents?

Comment: Same underlying topological space - not the same scheme! And that's not correct - a scheme could be non-reduced but still have the stalk at the generic point be a field if the nilpotence is contained in some proper closed subscheme. Think about $k[x,y]/(y^2,xy)$, for instance: this has some nilpotence at the origin, but $D(x)$ is the spectrum of $k[x,x^{-1}]$ and so the stalk at the generic point is $k(x)$.

Comment: @KReiser I see the point about the second part, not about the first part. I believe the projection on the quotient $p: R \twoheadrightarrow R/I$ induces a scheme isomorphism $Spec(R/I) \to V(I)$, am I wrong? Or it is just an homeomorphism and the morphism of sheaves can also be not an isomorphism?

Comment: An isomorphism of affine schemes is equivalent to an isomorphism of their coordinate rings. But $k$ and $k[x]/(x^2)$ are not isomorphic: one is a field, the other isn't. The correct thing is your final sentence there - there are plenty of scheme maps that are homeomorphisms but not isomorphisms due to the structure sheaf.

Comment: @KReiser I see, I had it under my nose. Thanks a lot.